# Does every sequence along a parametrized compact curve in a metric space converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

The question in the title naively appears to be true, for in a compact metric $X$ space every sequence has a convergent subsequence.  If $(a_n)$ traverses a compact curve $\Gamma$ then there is a convergent subsequence $(b_n)$.  But since (a_n) and (b_n) both traverse the same curve, they should converge to the same limit.

But this is very counterintuitive.  For example, I would not expect a sequence along some of the wilder space filling curves to converge, so I doubt my intuition.

EDIT:  With a curve $\Gamma$ parametrized by a continuous $\gamma: [0,1] \to X$

Comment: I don't understand your intuition. Take the sequence $e^{in}$: its elements lie in the unit circle which is compact, yet the sequence clearly doesn't converge.

Comment: Every sequence in a subset of  a metric space converges iff the set is a singleton.

Comment: Thank you @ArnaudMortier.  My post was too flippant and didn't include enough details. I've included the parametrization in an edit to make the post more complete and correct with regards to my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition may come from the fact that you're considering a compact curve in $X$ as being a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to X$ and a "sequence along a compact curve" as a sequence $u_n=f(x_n)$ where $x_n$ is an increasing sequence of points in $[0,1]$. In this case, your intuition is *correct*, since the sequence $x_n$ must converge to some limit $\ell$ (being an increasing and bounded sequence of reals) and therefore by continuity $u_n$ will converge to $f(\ell)$.

Comment: This is correct with regards to the intuition.  The motivation for this question was actually to show that a parametrized compact curve in a metric space cannot "diverge" by looking at sequences on it.